# Shift+volume control menu bar item

Tags: macos, sound-volume

On Mac OS X 10.8.2, shift-clicking the volume control menu extra causes a slider to come up. This slider's value is persistent, but different from the usual volume control's value.

What does this other slider control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shift click slider controls the volume for Alerts. You can check for yourself in the Sound preference pane.